# Combining data from multiple records into multiple columns of a single record in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, join, merging-data

Please find below my table structure and test data.

```
CREATE TABLE TX(
  TX_ID  VARCHAR2(10),
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(100),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_TX" PRIMARY KEY ("TX_ID")
);

CREATE TABLE PARTNER(
  TX_ID  VARCHAR2(10),
  PTNR_ID  VARCHAR2(10),
  PTNR_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
  PTNR_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_TX_PARTNER" PRIMARY KEY ("TX_ID", "PTNR_ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_TX_PARTNER" FOREIGN KEY ("TX_ID") REFERENCES TX("TX_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO TX VALUES('1','Transaction 1');
INSERT INTO TX VALUES('2','Transaction 2');
INSERT INTO TX VALUES('3','Transaction 3');
INSERT INTO TX VALUES('4','Transaction 4');
INSERT INTO TX VALUES('5','Transaction 5');

INSERT INTO PARTNER VALUES('1','P1', 'Partner 1', 'Exporter');
INSERT INTO PARTNER VALUES('1','P2', 'Partner 2', 'Importer');
INSERT INTO PARTNER VALUES('1','P3', 'Partner 3', 'Supplier');
INSERT INTO PARTNER VALUES('2','P1', 'Partner 1', 'Exporter');
INSERT INTO PARTNER VALUES('2','P2', 'Partner 2', 'Importer');
```

Now, I need to check the partner details associated with each transaction and show it in a single record. The output should be something like this.

```
TX_ID | DESCRIPTION    | PTNR_ID_1 | PTNR_NAME_1 | PTNR_ID_2 | PTNR_NAME_2 | PTNR_ID_3 | PTNR_NAME_3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | Transaction 1  | P1        | Partner 1   | P2        | Partner 2   | P3        | Partner 3
2     | Transaction 2  | P1        | Partner 1   | P2        | Partner 2
```

With below SQL query, I'm able to get the results I'm looking for. But I'm looking for a better way to achieve this.

```
SELECT 
  T.TX_ID AS "TRANSACTION ID",
  T.DESCRIPTION AS "DESCRIPTION", 
  P1.PTNR_ID AS "EXPORTER ID", 
  P1.PTNR_NAME AS "EXPORTER NAME",
  P2.PTNR_ID AS "IMPORTER ID", 
  P2.PTNR_NAME AS "IMPORTER NAME",
  P3.PTNR_ID AS "SUPPLIER ID", 
  P3.PTNR_NAME AS "SUPPLIER NAME"
FROM 
  TX T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTNER P1 ON (T.TX_ID = P1.TX_ID) AND P1.PTNR_TYPE='Exporter'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTNER P2 ON (T.TX_ID = P2.TX_ID) AND P2.PTNR_TYPE='Importer'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTNER P3 ON (T.TX_ID = P3.TX_ID) AND P3.PTNR_TYPE='Supplier';
```

**Edit:**
I tried with inner query and case combination, as mentioned below. It was not returning the data in a required way. I'm getting duplicate records. For different partner types, different records have resulted. I'm not sure how to merge these results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRANSACTION_ID, DESCRIPTION, EXPORTER_ID, EXPORTER_NAME, IMPORTER_ID, IMPORTER_NAME, SUPPLIER_ID, SUPPLIER_NAME
FROM (
        SELECT 
          T.TX_ID AS "TRANSACTION_ID",
          T.DESCRIPTION AS "DESCRIPTION", 
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Exporter' THEN P1.PTNR_ID ELSE NULL END) AS "EXPORTER_ID", 
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Exporter' THEN P1.PTNR_NAME ELSE NULL END) AS "EXPORTER_NAME",
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Importer' THEN P1.PTNR_ID ELSE NULL END) AS "IMPORTER_ID", 
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Importer' THEN P1.PTNR_NAME ELSE NULL END) AS "IMPORTER_NAME",
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Supplier' THEN P1.PTNR_ID ELSE NULL END) AS "SUPPLIER_ID", 
          (CASE WHEN P1.PTNR_TYPE = 'Supplier' THEN P1.PTNR_NAME ELSE NULL END) AS "SUPPLIER_NAME"
        FROM 
          TX T
          INNER JOIN PARTNER P1 ON (T.TX_ID = P1.TX_ID) AND P1.PTNR_TYPE= ANY('Exporter', 'Importer', 'Supplier')
);
```

Also, I'm looking for an Oracle SQL solution but not PL/SQL solution. I can use BEGIN...END blocks but not cursors.

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: @Eric, I'm looking for a solution in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in different ways, try this method. Use `inner join` instead

```
SELECT 
  T.TX_ID AS "TRANSACTION ID",
  T.DESCRIPTION AS "DESCRIPTION", 
  (select PTNR_ID from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Exporter' )AS "EXPORTER ID", 
  (select PTNR_NAME from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Exporter' ) AS "EXPORTER NAME",
  (select PTNR_ID from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Importer' ) AS "IMPORTER ID", 
  (select PTNR_NAME from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Importer' ) AS "IMPORTER NAME",
  (select PTNR_ID from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Supplier' ) AS "SUPPLIER ID", 
   (select PTNR_NAME from partner where PTNR_TYPE='Supplier' )    AS "SUPPLIER NAME"
FROM 
  TX T
  inner join partner p on p.tx_id = t.tx_id
```

Comment: @B House, this will not work. In the sub-query, there is no linking to the TX table and so each sub-query will return multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the partner information as a single column instead of separate columns, try this, using Oracles "analytical function" called LISTAGG:

```
select a.tx_id,
       a.description,
       sub.result
  from tx a,
       (select b.tx_id,
               listagg('<' || b.ptnr_id || ' ' || b.ptnr_name || '>', ' ')
                within group (order by b.ptnr_id) as result
          from partner b
          group by b.tx_id
         ) sub
 where a.tx_id = sub.tx_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I need the data in different columns.

Comment: You have an issue with returning "0 or 1 or 20 or ..." partners in each row.  SQL needs to know number of columns in a row if you intend to INSERT the result or even display it.  Straight SQL does not go searching for any number of columns for each row easily.  PL/SQL can using a "NESTED TABLE" that can grow to most any size (well, not unlimited really but there is a practical limit on partners).  The NESTED TABLE can even be stored in a table as-is.  But you indicated you do not want to deal with advanced PL/SQL (COLLECTIONs, CURSORs, etc).  I have no "easy" solution that is also not dynamic.

Comment: This was an example I created to address a very big query which I was working on. I would like to clarify that the number of columns will not change in my requirement. For now, let us say, I would like to show only 'Exporter' and 'Importer in this query. In future, if I need to add 'Supplier' information as well, I'll add those columns and do the changes accordingly. In short, the columns are not growing for a given scenario/ query. Are there any solutions you can think of now?

Comment: If the data rules limit 1 "type" ("Importer", "Exporter", "Supplier", etc) for each partner id, you can use more-static SQL.  You do not have any such limit in the table description, so the probability for "many returned columns" still exists.  Is the data model limited in that way?

Comment: Yes, 1 partner ID per partner type. Even, I'm ready to add partner type to the composite primary key, for better clarification.